# Find a lot of buttons using a for loop (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a lot of buttons created and now I want to "get" them using `findViewById` and a for loop:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Array buttons[];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        String buttonID = "number" + i;
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
        buttons[i] = ((Button) findViewById(resID));
    }
  }
}
```

But in the line

```
buttons[i] = ((Buttons) findViewById(resID));
```

I get this error:

> Incompatible types. Required: java.lang.reflect.Array Found:
>   android.widget.button

Comment: If so then which one do I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the

```
Array buttons[];
```

To

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[10];
```

Comment: Great answer if you know that at most there will be 10 buttons. If you are unsure probably better to use an ArrayList<Button>. Like this.. `ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();` And then `buttons.add(((Button) findViewById(resID)));`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Array buttons[];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

buttons = new Button[10];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    String buttonID = "number" + i;
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
    buttons[i] = ((Button) findViewById(resID));
}
```

}
}